# Исправить кодировку текста PHP

Tags: php, sql, csv, utf-8

Здраствуйте. Делал запись в бд из csv файлов. Запись работает. В самих csv файлах есть проблема с кодировкой. Например:

`Íå îáäåë¸í ïíåâìàòè÷åñêîé òåõíèêîé, ïîýòîìó ñåáå ïîêóïàòü íîâûõ èãðóøåê íå ïëàíèðîâàë. Íî ïðèøëîñü ñðî÷íî èñêàòü ÇÈÏ äëÿ îäíîé ìåäòåõíèêè, à íåìöû ïðîñèëè ïîä 5000 ïðè÷åì íå ôàêò, ÷òî ïîäîøëî áû.&nbsp;Â èòîãå ìèìî ìåíÿ ïðîñëåäîâàë äàííûé êîìïðåññîð.&nbsp`.

Мне надо преобразовать это в нормальный текст, кирилицу. Есть может быть какие-то встроеные функции или свои способы исправления кодировки в PHP?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: mb_convert_encoding Пробовал не помогло

Comment: откройте исходный файл в notepad++ , посмотрите кодировку. если винды, скорее всего 1251. попробуйте явно ее указать

Comment: Кодировка стоит UTF-8

Comment: пробовал раскодировать на http://www.online-decoder.com/ и все работает на сайте. Но когда я ввожу те же кодировки у себя в коде, то все остается так же. Просто вместо Íå `îáäåë`  уже `ÃÃ¥ Ã®Ã¡Ã¤Ã¥Ã«Â`

Comment: Данный набор символов выглядит как русский текст, сохраненный в кодировке win-1251 (русская), и прочитанный как win-1252 (западноевропейская). Соответственно вам нужно явно указать, что нужно использовать win1251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам @Герман Борисов верно подсказал причину. Исправить можно, например, так:

```
<?php

$text = <<< EOT
Íå îáäåë¸í ïíåâìàòè÷åñêîé òåõíèêîé, ïîýòîìó ñåáå ïîêóïàòü íîâûõ èãðóøåê íå ïëàíèðîâàë. Íî ïðèøëîñü ñðî÷íî èñêàòü ÇÈÏ äëÿ îäíîé ìåäòåõíèêè, à íåìöû ïðîñèëè ïîä 5000 ïðè÷åì íå ôàêò, ÷òî ïîäîøëî áû.&nbsp;Â èòîãå ìèìî ìåíÿ ïðîñëåäîâàë äàííûé êîìïðåññîð.&nbsp.
EOT;

$original = iconv("utf8", "cp1252", $text);
echo iconv("cp1251", "utf8", $original);
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c66946a59de4ccdcca5ae950e46d8333042345b6)